# How to close flutter speed dial when tap on a label widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to close the flutter `speedDial` when tap on a `label` widget?. I did not use SpeedDial's `child` property, but it has that feature. Currently when I tap on a label widget it stays until I manually close the widget. Or even a way to change the child property of SpeedDial widget would be enough, while I want a custom shape like in the picture.

```
Navigator.pop()  did not work
```

[image: sample image]

```
                      SpeedDial(
                                buttonSize: const Size(45, 45),
                                animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                                children: [
                                  SpeedDialChild(
                                    labelWidget: GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        Feedback.forTap(context);
                                        await _crudStorage.deleteAllTask();
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 50.0,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color:
                                              Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                                          border: Border.all(width: 2.0),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          children: [
                                            const Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  left: 12.0, right: 8.0),
                                              child:
                                                  Text('Clear all tasks'),
                                            ),
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                      right: 8.0),
                                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/svg/all.svg',
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so simple. Also the development team, provided how to implement this on their official extension page on pub.dev [go to pub](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial). I will mention the same documentation for your reference:

first you need to create a value notifier:

```
ValueNotifier<bool> isDialOpen = ValueNotifier(false);
```

Then set openCloseDial to isDialOpen in your SpeedDial:

```
SpeedDial(
  ...
  openCloseDial: isDialOpen,
  ...
)
```

Now you can change the state of dial open:

```
isDialOpen.value = false;
```

Example: Just set the value to `false` inside the `onTap` callback  :)

```
 onTap: () async {
                   Feedback.forTap(context);
                   await _crudStorage.deleteAllTask();
                   isDialOpen.value = false;
                 },
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use async & await on tap use separate function to Call

https://tutorialmeta.com/question/how-to-call-async-function-with-ontap-flutter

refer the above link

Answer (score 0):

use `closeManually: false` in `SpeedDial` Contructor.  The widget will close automatically on select any function.

Answer (score 0):

With some observation, the problem was somehow related to adding "animationDuration" in the "SpeedDial" Contructor.

```
  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I want to redirect to another page when click on item of my SpeedDial. I close SpeedDial by following step:

1. Setting in SpeedDial:

> SpeedDial( ... closeManually: false ... )

2. In SpeedDialChild, onTap:

   onTap: () {

   ```
   Future.delayed(
    const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    () => Get.toNamed(Redirecto another page})
   ```

   );
   },

Good luck!